# как взять координаты начала и конца растоянии?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

У меня 2 кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп", карта *google maps api v2*.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки *старт* назначалась начальная точка, а при *Стоп* — конечная. И считалось между ними расстояние, скорость.

подскажите, как взять начало и конец?

я пытался делать, но приложение вылетает *force closed* при нажатии на кнопку *старт*.

вот мой код:

```
    package com.example.tuantv.slidingtabsdemo2;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Admin on 6/26/2015.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements LocationListener, View.OnClickListener{

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 30000;


    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private Button buttonStart;
    private Button buttonStop;
    private Button buttonReset;
    private Chronometer chronometerRun;
    private double latStart;
    private double lonStart;
    private double latStop;
    private double lonStop;
    private LatLng latLngStart;
    private LatLng latLngStop;
    private TextView textViewDistance;
    Location location;
    long time = 0;

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

        textViewDistance = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance);
        buttonStart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        buttonReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);

        chronometerRun = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.chronometerRunning);




        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(this);

//        double distance = CalculationByDistance(latLngStart,latLngStop);

        initMap();
        return view;
    }

    public void initMap(){

        if (googleMap == null) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        }

        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttonStart:
                chronometerRun.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - time);
                chronometerRun.start();
                latStart = location.getLatitude();
                // Getting longitude of the current location
                lonStart = location.getLongitude();
                // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
                latLngStart = new LatLng(latStart, lonStart);
                break;
            case  R.id.buttonStop:
                time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometerRun.getBase();
                chronometerRun.stop();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonReset:
                time = 0;
                chronometerRun.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chronometerRun.stop();
                latStop = location.getLatitude();
                // Getting longitude of the current location
                lonStop = location.getLongitude();
                // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
                latLngStop = new LatLng(latStop, lonStop);
                break;
        }
        double distance = CalculationByDistance(latLngStart,latLngStop);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: где StackTrace ошибки?

Comment: там в button Start где "latStart = location.getLatitude();"

Comment: нет, выложите сюда стак трейс.

Comment: извините, я начинающий, что такое stack trace? и где это взять?

Comment: Какая инициализация у location в вашем коде?

Comment: я добавил польный код, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Скорее всего валится из-за `location==null`. Добавьте проверку:

   ```
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (location == null) return;
       //...
   ```
2. Вызов `double distance = CalculationByDistance(latLngStart,latLngStop);` наверное лучше перенесли в ветку `case R.id.buttonReset:` или сделать проверку на `null` для `latLngStart` `latLngStop`.

Про стектрейс:

```
try {
    //...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я сделал

Comment: В чем была проблема?

Comment: double distance = CalculationByDistance(latLngStart,latLngStop);
вот это надо было писать внутри buttonReset перед break.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста. Дистанцию посчитал, время нужно взять из chronometer, как взять значение из chronometer чтоб посчитать скорость?

Comment: if (time > 0 ) { double v = distance / time; } // time in ms

Comment: только вам нужно немного изменить последовательность блока buttonReset: 1. получить latLngStop, 2. посчитать distance, 3. вычислить скорость, 4. обнулить time. 5. сбросить chronometerRun

Comment: в комментарии time это в миллисекунд?

Comment: Да, в миллисекундах. (time in ms)